# Undefined reference to `CkMailMan::put_SmtpHost(Char const*)

Tags: c++, qt

I want this program to send emails, and I'm trying to do that with Qt

emailer.h

```
#ifndef EMAILER_H
#define EMAILER_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Emailer;
}

class Emailer : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Emailer(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Emailer();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

void on_radioButton_toggled(bool checked);

void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

void ChilkatSample();

 private:
 Ui::Emailer *ui;
 };

 #endif // EMAILER_H
```

WARNING This code is so catastrophic that gave me a headache just to remember what I coded

```
emailer.cpp

#include "emailer.h"
#include "ui_emailer.h"
#include <CkMailMan.h>
#include <CkEmail.h>
#include "QString"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
Emailer::Emailer(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Emailer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}



Emailer::~Emailer()
{
    delete ui;
}

//Bug

void Emailer::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}
//bug

CkMailMan mailman;
 bool success = mailman.UnlockComponent("test");
 CkEmail email;

void Emailer::ChilkatSample()
    {
    QString Subject = ui->label_4->text();
    QString Body = ui->label_5->text();
    QString Mailer = ui->label->text();
    std::string Subject1 = Subject.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    std::string Body1 = Body.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    std::string Mailer1 = Mailer.toLocal8Bit().constData();

    //  Set the SMTP server.
    mailman.put_SmtpHost("smtp.gmail.com");

    //  Set the SMTP login/password (if required)
    mailman.put_SmtpUsername("***");
    mailman.put_SmtpPassword("***");

    //  Create a new email object

    email.put_Subject(Subject1.c_str());
    email.put_Body(Body1.c_str());
    email.put_From("","***");
    success = email.AddTo("",Mailer1.c_str());
}
bool caca = false;
void Emailer::on_radioButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    caca = true;
}
void Emailer::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if (caca == false){
        success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
    if (success != true) {

        return;
    }

    success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
    if (success != true) {

    }

    }
    else if (caca == true){
        QString Days = ui->label_7->text();
         std::string Days1 = Days.toLocal8Bit().constData();
         int Days2 = std::stoi(Days1,nullptr,0);
       for (int i = 0;i == ui->label_7->text();i++){
           success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
       if (success != true) {

           return;
       }

       success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
       if (success != true) {

       }


           Sleep(Days2 * 86400000);
       }
    }
}
```

Emailer.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-12-05T22:32:50
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Emailer
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        emailer.cpp

HEADERS  += emailer.h \
    CkCrypt2.h \
    CkEmail.h \
    CkMailMan.h \
    CkObject.h \
    CkString.h

FORMS    += emailer.ui
```

and this is the output (fun fact: you fix that last one error BOOM 16 more errors)

Output raw:

https://pastebin.com/pMrQ3Mcr

Output:

[Issues output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biyBF.png)

I got more headers files most of them are ck things and their sources can be fetched from GitHub, I only had to add an #include windows.h to Ckmailman.h source

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: Done, I've just added the .pro file source

Comment: I do not see that you have linked the library to your project: `LIBS +=`

Comment: So basically I have to LIBS += all the headers? I've just started with QT sorry if I do stupid question

Comment: Do you have .dlls or .lib?

Comment: No, i don't have any .lib or .DLL

Comment: Could you tell me where you got the .h?

Comment: I got CkString and CkObject for this site: https://codeload.github.com/clickteam-plugin/PBKDF2/zip/master
and CkMail and CkMailman form GitHub, I had to make a change in CkMailman.h I had to add an #include <windows.h> for it to work

Comment: This project has the .lib, you have to link it, follow the next manual to do it: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: but I don't have any .lib or .dll if I need to add some lib, what lib I need to add

Comment: You have 2, check your repo: https://github.com/clickteam-plugin/PBKDF2, Debug: ChilkatDbg.lib and release: ChilkatRel.lib, If you have any problems I could help you through teamviewer.

Comment: I added the debug library and the release one as a dynamic and I get this error: cannot find -lChilkatDbgd/Rel I tried each on separate and I get the same error, I tried to add them as a static library and this error pop up,  No rule to make target 'C:/Users/.../Documents/Emailer/./libChilkatDbgd.a', needed by 'debug\Emailer.exe'.  Stop.